# I need clarity on Javascript prototyping and syntatical (sugar) class implementation from the following lines of code

Tags: javascript, prototype

If i was to use this line `Book.prototype.clearFields = function ()` anywhere in my code it would be by means of instantiating.

```js
deleteBook = (element) => {

    if (element.classList.contains("delete")) {
        element.parentElement.remove();
    }

};
```

Therefore does this mean that the `deleteBook()` function would be a representation of a static method if this was in an actual js class, thus avoiding to instantiate a new book, i can just call it directly?

Comment: what is the relationship between `clearFields` and `deleteBook`?

Comment: "this line ... **anywhere** in my code it **would** ...", "the `deleteBook()` function **would** ..." please be more specific, ideally post some specific code showing what would be the same and where you put the code..

Answer (score 0):

The way it is written, I do not believe so.

If you have:

```
class Book{
  deleteMe = elem => {
    //some code here not referencing 'this'
    console.log('deleted');
  }
}

Book.deleteMe(null);
```

You will get a type error. However if you instantiate, it would work:

```
const myBook = new Book();
myBook.deleteMe(null);
```

Most likely, if you are instantiating, you wouldn't pass in an argument, but would instead reference `this`, but that's a side note.

I do not know what the browser native code does for classes under the hood, but Babel can give us an idea by transpiling it back to pre-class code. Throwing that code into Babel ES2015 (i.e. pre-class), it looks like:

```
"use strict";

function _instanceof(left, right) { if (right != null && typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && right[Symbol.hasInstance]) { return !!right[Symbol.hasInstance](left); } else { return left instanceof right; } }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!_instanceof(instance, Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) { if (key in obj) { Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { value: value, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true }); } else { obj[key] = value; } return obj; }

var Book = function Book() {
  _classCallCheck(this, Book);

  _defineProperty(this, "deleteMe", function (elem) {
    //some code here not referencing 'this'
    console.log('deleted');
  });
};

Book.deleteMe(null);
```

So looking at the function `Book` that comes out of there, it has no properties. When you call it, it uses those helper functions to modify the object it is creating, i.e. `this` and add functions to *that* object, but not itself. So you can't call it directly like that.

Interestingly, if you add the word `static` before the function, Babel does a neat trick and moves that `_defineProperty` call that sets up the deleteMe function *outside* of the `Book` function. So it looks like this instead:

```
var Book = function Book() {
  _classCallCheck(this, Book);
};

_defineProperty(Book, "deleteMe", function (elem) {
  //some code here not referencing 'this'
  console.log('deleted');
});
```

So instead of adding the function `deleteMe` to `this`, it adds it to `Book`. This means the function lives on the class itself, not on its instance, which makes it callable like you wish:

`Book.deleteMe(null);`